# What are the steps to run Login scenario in jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I have installed Jmeter. I tested the load for google using www.google.com, it is working fine but when i tried with https://www.google.com it is not working fine. what are the steps to test login scenario in Jmeter. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The "classic" login test plan looks as follows:

- Thread Group

  - [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) (to set host, port, protocol, path, etc. for all HTTP Request samplers in scope)
  - [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) (to maintain session and deal with cookie-based authenticaion)
  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) (GET request to login page)

    - Regular Expression Extractor or similar (if any dynamic mandatory parameters are required for login request they need to be extracted here)
  - HTTP Request (POST request to login page with username, password, and dynamic parameters if any)

    - [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) (to verify that login was successful)

Useful links:

1. [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
2. [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)
3. [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)